# How to get per facet p-value in ggsurvplot_facet function

Tags: r, survival, survminer

I have a simple question: in using survminer::ggsurvplot_facet function, how can I get the p-value calculcated per each facet? It's displayed on the plot, but I just want to save it for other analysis. Thanks.

```
sfit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ Group, data=d_filter)

ggsurvplot_facet(sfit, d_filter, facet.by = "Facet", ncol=wNum,
                title='Survival Curve', legend.title=var_metric,  
                 palette = "npg", conf.int=FALSE, pval = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?